# Python- Get information from matching keys in two dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to build a function that combines two dictionaries. It should be easy but there is a catch.

Given two dictionaries:

```
info_format_dict={ name: (id, type1, type2, generation, legendary), 
'Bulbasaur': (1, 'Grass', 'Poison', 1, False), 'Charmander': (4, 
'Fire', None, 1, False)}

stats_format_dict={ id: (hp, attack, defense, speed),1: (45, 49, 49, 
45)}
```

I must combine the dictionaries ONLY IF the id numbers are found in both. So in this example, from info_format_dict 'Bulbasaur' has id 1 and in stats_format_dict, 1 is the id number. They match. Then I must add that item to a new dictionary in the following format:

```
new_dict={"Bulbasaur": (1, "Grass", "Poison", 45, 49, 49, 45, 1, 
False)}
```

Any others that don't have a match just get discarded. The function I created makes the dictionaries into lists for comparison, but I get stuck on how to do the actual combining once I found the matches. How do I do the actual combining and is my checking correct?

Here is my code:

```
def combine_databases(info_format_dict,stats_format_dict):
    statskeyslist=[]
    idnums=[]   
    for key,values in info_format_dict.items():
        idnum=values[0]
        idnums.append(idnums)

    for keys in stats_format_dict:
        stats_key=keys
        statskeyslist.append(keys) 

    for item in statskeyslist:
        if item in idums:
        #combine them into a dictionary
```

Suggestions? Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You have the keys that are in both in the inside of your inner loop. (You should be able to reason why, given that you created them above!) Why don't you try getting the values from each dictionary and attempt to combine them?

```
v1 = info_format_dict[item]
v2 = stats_format_dict[item]
```

You should be able to guarantee that there won't be an exception thrown here. (Why?)

You'll then need to stick them into some other dict to return.

Comment: In which order? Before or after the keys?

Comment: Well, what makes sense? Do you understand how adding an item to a dict would work? Try both and see what happens.